# $routeParams sending object with properties as string containing '/'

Tags: angularjs

I am novice in AngularJS. I was trying to send an object from one controller to another using `$routeParams`.

```
$location.path("/addMyResults/"+JSON.stringify($scope.resultsObj));
```

This is how i am routing:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/addMyResults/:myresultsObj',{
    templateUrl : 'partials/myResultsAdd.html',
    controller : 'AddMyResultsController'
});
```

and collecting the object in another controller as:

```
$scope.resultsObj = angular.fromJson($routeParams.resultsObj);
```

The resultsObj has two string properties name & address.
When `'/'` is entered into the address string(infact any field) the routing does not work.

Please let me know if there is some solution.

Comment: You should create an service to deal with data in multiple controllers.But you're able to put your object to `$rootScope` which can be accessed from everywhere. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope

Comment: Examples over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880737/how-do-i-use-rootscope-in-angular-to-store-variables

Answer (score -1):

```
'/addMyResults/:myresultsObj',
```

Comment: kindly consider adding more details as to how this solves the problem.