# Accessing scope variable in function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm still learning AngularJS and I'm trying to (for example) switch the names on a regular interval. I've got most of the basic idea down but I'm running into problems with how Angular handles how information is shared I've tried this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nwz5krw4/1/
The core of the fiddle is this (where names is an array of names):

```
this.changeName = function($scope,names)
    {
        this.nameIndex++;
        if ($scope.$parent.nameIndex > (names.size - 1))
        {
            $scope.$parent.nameIndex = names[0];
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.$parent.myName = names[$scope.$parent.nameIndex];
        }

    };
```

Oddly, that will load in the browser and give me the first name, then simply refuse to change Reading the console reveals that t. Another path I've taken based on [How do I use $rootScope in Angular to store variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880737/how-do-i-use-rootscope-in-angular-to-store-variables) is to create this:

```
app.run(function($rootScope){

});
```

And place my array of names in there as $rootScope.names. Obviously $rootScope is to be avoided where possible, but right now I'm just going for functionality. However, this, too, did not work. Passing $scope to the method resulted in $scope.names or $rootScope.names being undefined. I'm not yet "thinking in Angular" and need some mental translation to make the leap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass `$scope` and `names` to the `this.changeName` method.

Just create a reference to this e.g. name it vm, self or that and then you can use your object variables inside of the method. That's required because this is different in the $interval callback.

Alternatively you could bind this to the callback and your won't need to store the reference.

Please find the working demo below and here at [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/nwz5krw4/2/).

```js
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('hello-world', []);

    app.controller('helloController', function ($scope, $interval) {
        // Create an array of names.
        var names = [
            "Jed",
            "Leo",
            "Josh",
            "Toby",
            "Sam",
            "CJ",
            "Donna",
            "Charlie",
            "Delores",
            "Abby",
            "Will"];

        // Set initial values for on-page elements
        var vm = this; // reference to view-model
        this.myName = names[0];
        this.nameIndex = 0;
        
        /**
         * Changes the name when called.
         */
        this.changeName = function () {
            vm.nameIndex = vm.nameIndex++ >= names.length - 1 ? 0: vm.nameIndex; 
            vm.myName = names[vm.nameIndex];
            console.log(vm.myName, vm.nameIndex);
        };

        $interval(this.changeName, 2000);
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="hello-world">
    <div ng-controller="helloController as hi">
        
<h1 style="text-align: center" ng-style="{'color':hi.myColor}">Hello, {{hi.myName}}</h1>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so first of all. A really good tip when doing controllerAs syntax, in your controller, assign this to a variable.

```
var hi = this;
```

This will avoid any weird internal this conflicts, and you wont have to mess with rootScope or $parent or any of that nonsense.

So I switched it to using that and it works fine. I also moved over to plunker because JSFiddle is pretty crappy and was giving me a bunch of strange angular errors. Anyways, here is a working fiddle

http://plnkr.co/edit/53Md9eAZmq0gRRs1hfkp?p=preview

You will see, all I did was change all the $scope.$parent to use the new variable that 'this' was assigned to.

Comment: Yours was first and was an equally good answer but I gave the checkmark to AWolf due to the on-page example making it easier for those who follow. Thanks to both of you!