# How do I change rootScope into Service in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and still learning.

Here is the [sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/6corv0mc/3/).

I would like to know how do I convert it to a service? I find writing both setStatus on `NavController` and `HeaderController` seems quite wrong, are there any better way working for this one?

**Scenario**

When the user click on `close` button, the whole `nav` which with background will be displayed none while when the user clicked on `menu` button, `nav` will get a class of `is-active` which makes the `nav` displayed block.

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('NavController', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    $rootScope.status = 'off';
    this.setStatus = function(status) {
        $rootScope.status = status;
    };
});

app.controller('HeaderController', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    this.setStatus = function(status) {
        $rootScope.status = status;
    };
});
```

**DOM**

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <nav ng-controller="NavController as nav" ng-class="{ 'is-active': status == 'on' }" ng-init="nav.status" class="nav">
    <div class="nav__wrapper">
      <button ng-click="nav.setStatus('off')" class="nav__close">close</button>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <header ng-controller="HeaderController as header">
    <button ng-click="header.setStatus('on')">menu</button>
  </header>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: For the fiddle to work (at least not fail with unknown module), click the Javascript options in the Javascript pane and select "Load type: No wrap - in < body >"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things which caused the issue on JSFiddle

- The angular js library was being loaded `onload` which is parsing the script way before the module `myapp` defined, so the `LoadType` on JSFiddle should be `No Wrap-in<body>`
- The styles which has been dumped in JSFiddle needs to be RAW CSS & not less/sass, since JSFIddle would not parse those to CSS.

I corrected those things & your JSFiddle worked smoothly ;)

[Running JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/6corv0mc/3/)

Now, regarding the actual issue of moving the common/sharable data to factory /service is achieved by creating a simple factory module like below & referring it all controllers

**JS CODE:**

```
myApp.factory('Data', function () {
   return { FirstName: '' };
});

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope, Data) {
   $scope.Data = Data;
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function ($scope, Data) {
   $scope.Data = Data;
});
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="Data.FirstName">
  <br>Input is : <strong>{{Data.FirstName}}</strong>
</div>
<hr>
<div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
  Input should also be here: {{Data.FirstName}}
</div>
```

[Live Demo using factory/service @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HEdJF/)

*Note: Using `$rootScope` for defining a global object like in your current code itself is a decent way of doing things, but anyway the same can be achieved using defining a new `factory` module like above.*

References :

- Using $rootScope : [How do I use $rootScope in Angular to store variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880737/how-do-i-use-rootscope-in-angular-to-store-variables)
- using service/factory module : [Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: thank you, changed on the original post. Although my main issue is how to convert the rootScope into service.

Comment: thanks again, I used custom directive instead, seems like that's the perfect way to use it instead of using service/factory without any datas sharing anyway.