# angularjs nested controllers - form undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, undefined

I have the following html structure:

```
<body ng-controller="checkoutController">
    <div class="main clearfix" ng-controller="abroadCourseController">
        //html useless information
        <form name="checkout_form" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
            <div validate-section="checkoutInfo" ng-show="stepOne">
                //fields
                <div class="confirmationBox">
                    <button type="button" ng-click="displayPaymentMethods()">SHOW PAYMENT METHODS</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div validate-section="paymentAbroadCourseB2C" ng-show="stepTwo" >
                //fields
                <div class="confirmationBox">
                    <button type="button" ng-click="submitForm()">FINISH</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the following js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('checkoutController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.submitForm = function(){
     $scope.stepOne = true;
     $scope.stepTwo = false;

     alert($scope.checkout_form);
     alert('oi');  
  };  
});

myApp.controller('abroadCourseController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.stepOne = true;
  $scope.stepTwo = false;

  $scope.displayPaymentMethods = function(){
     $scope.stepOne = false;
     $scope.stepTwo = true;

     alert($scope.checkout_form);
     alert('oi');  
  };  
});
```

basically what I need is to have access on checkout_form through the parent controller, however, it's undefined. Is there a way to achieve that?

Here's a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thm259o7/

Comment: you can use $rootScope for that

Comment: you said it is undefined on the parent controller - what about the child controller? is it undefined there too? PS don't use alert as it freezes the thread and causes lots of problems in angular, use console.log instead. in fact using alert may be your problem

Comment: @danday74 console.log is disabled on jsfiddle

Comment: @danday74 in the child controller it has value. You can check on js fiddle

Comment: ok thanks for clarifying that - please remove use of alert and let me know what happens - send output to the text in a div or something

Comment: @RajatBhadauria in the parent controller? or in the child one?

Comment: in the parent it is undefined, in the nested child it is set

Comment: @danday74 same problem http://jsfiddle.net/thm259o7/1/

Comment: If `checkoutController` needs access to `checkout_form`, then why is the form defined for `abroadCourseController`?

Comment: @zeroflagL both use the form. this question is a mock of my real problem.

Comment: It doesn't matter if both use the form or not. If something is not declared in the scope of a controller (or maybe its parent controller) then it's not the controller's business. You have an architectural problem, not so much a technical one.

Comment: just define $rootScope in parent Controller or child Controller you can access the $rootScope in any controller ..

Comment: you can use the following link for that   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880737/how-do-i-use-rootscope-in-angular-to-store-variables

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with nested controllers in Angular is using the Controller As Syntax https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Change your code like this:

```
myApp.controller('abroadCourseController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.form.checkout_form = {}
```

And then change the HTML like this:

```
<form name="form.checkout_form" ...>
```

In my case, It works.