# How to check $window variable in ng-if or ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I declared one variable var variable1 and i need to check variable in all pages using ng-if or ng-show

Answer (score 0):

one of the ways is to attach the variable to the `$rootScope`. For example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
...
app.run(function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.myspecialvar = "hello";
});


...
//can be used in js
app.controller(function($rootScope){
  console.log($rootScope.myspecialvar);
});
```

```html
<!-- can be used in html -->
{{myspecialvar}}
<!-- or -->
<div ng-if='myspecialvar'></div>
```

Read here about `$rootScope`: [How do I use $rootScope in Angular to store variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880737/how-do-i-use-rootscope-in-angular-to-store-variables)