# Angular: access $scope variables in $root via a template

Tags: angularjs, scope

Here's a snippet of an [angular google map](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/):

```
<ui-gmap-markers models='theWinner' events="map.markerEvents" coords='"coordinates"'>
    <ui-gmap-windows show="show">
        <div ng-non-bindable>{{ coordinates }}</div>
        <div ng-click="$root.derp(coordinates)">navigate</div>
    </ui-gmap-windows>
</ui-gmap-markers>
```

I need `derp()` to be in `$root` in order to use it from within the angular google map. I also need to pass the `coordinates` which are defined in regular ol' `$scope`. As-is, the above code does not work. `{{ coordinates }}` are available to the template, but not they are *not* passed to `$root.derp()`.

What's the cleanest way to fix this problem? Thanks!

Edit: It occurs to me that I could explicitly create a copy of the `coordinates` in a `$root` variable, like so:

```
$scope.$root.coordinates = coordinates;
```

Kind of messy, having two copies of the same variable, but it works. Is there a better way? I don't like abusing $root more than I have to.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly do you need derp() to be in `$root`? If its for the sake of sharing data between controllers you should use a factory/service.
If there is no way around as you already answered yourself the correct way is to "copy"/set the value.
[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880737/how-do-i-use-rootscope-in-angular-to-store-variables)