# How to call one controller method from another controller in angular javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I try to call one controller method from another controller in the angular javascript, an error occurs. I think something is missing there. If anyone has the complete method to do this, please give me the answer.

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: What is the scope of the method you are calling ?
Is it bindto controller scope or rootScope?

Comment: *"I think something is missing there."* - Yes, the code is missing.

Answer (score 3):

Being able to share a variables throught different controllers it's a common issue in angular.

Your function can be seen as an *object*: you'll need to share it's reference throught scopes.

To perform that, you can either:
.

### **Use a service**:

You can see services as singletons object that are *injected* in your controllers: a common object shared throught your controllers.

You can use [this](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/services) wonderful guide to understand how to share your scope variables by using services (this guide uses factory and not services,  but for your needs will be ok).
If you still wants to use services, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12009408/1306679) answer.

.

### **Use scope hierarchy**:

Sometimes you have a *hierarchy* between controllers (and thus, scopes).
Let's assume you have an HTML formatted this way:

```
<div ng-controller="parentController">
   <!-- some content here...-->
   <div ng-controller="childController">
      <!-- some content here...-->
   </div>
</div>
```

This structure will produces two different scopes: one for parentController, and one for childController.
So, you childController scope will be able to access parentController scope by simply using $parent object. For example:

```
myApp.controller('parentController', function($scope) {
    $scope.functionExample = function(){
      console.log('hey there');
    };
})

myApp.controller('childController', function($scope) {
    $scope.functionExample();
});
```

Note: the parent object is accesible directly in your child scope, *even if declared in your parent.*

But **beware** of this method: you can't never really sure of your scope hierarchy, so a check if the variable is defined should be always needed.

.

### **Use $rootScope**:

You can use rootscope as a common shared object to share yours. But beware: this way, you'll risk to pollute your $rootScope of variables when $rootScope should be used for other uses (see message broadcasting).

Anyway, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18881189/1306679) answer for an example use case.

.

### **Use Messages**:

By using messages, you can share objects references, as shown in this example:

```
myApp.controller('parentController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
     var object = { test: 'test'}
     $rootScope.$broadcast('message', message)
     console.log('broadcasting');
});


myApp.controller('childController', function($scope, $rootScope) {            
     $scope.$on('message', function(message){
        console.log(message);
     });
});
```

.

In the end, i suggest you to use a common service for all your variables or, where you can, use the scope hierarchy method.

Answer (score 0):

If two controllers are nested in one controller,
then you can simply call the other by using:

```
$scope.parentMethod();
```

Angular will search for `parentMethod()` function starting with the current scope up to it reach the `$rootscope`