# I want store response and use it globally

Tags: angular

Below code is for login functionality. And in this response I got whole data of particular user. I want to store whole data of current user and use it in other page for edit profile.

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    var body = 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, body, options)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            let success = response.json() && response.json().success;
            if (success) {
                this.token = success;
               user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: success }));
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: You could store it into the `$rootScope`, though some might view this as being evil.

Comment: please explain briefly @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880737/how-do-i-use-rootscope-in-angular-to-store-variables

Comment: You could use a service provider to store the data, and access the same all over the application.

Comment: still confused in my example

Comment: please explain briefly @ Ranjith Varadan

Comment: you could use something like this to store and access the data, [sample src](https://github.com/darthranjith/simpledatacommunication/blob/master/src/providers/simple-sharing.ts)

Comment: If you still have doubts, you can refer this [tutorial](http://varanjith.com/simple-data-communication-between-components-using-services/)

Comment: but in login functionality I am passed username and password so that in current user I only got the username and password. But I want id of the current user so I can edit profile of current user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing a bit of `TypeScript`, I believe this is Angular (not AngularJS, although not sure).

With Angular, you can achieve this by creating a service and providing it at the module level providers.

In your app.module.ts, register the service as:

```
@NgModule({
      imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule ], 
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
      providers: [
          MyGlobalService
      ]
})
```

create this service and inject is a dependency in the corresponding `component/service/directive` where your `login` function is. Thereafter once on receiving data, you can store it into the service like:

```
    if (success) {
            this.token = success;
           user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: 
            username, token: success }));
            this.myGlobalService.setUserData(response);
            return true;
        }
```

Of course you will have to implement `setUserData` function in the service. Like:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyGlobalService{

private userData :any;

  setUserData(data){
    this.userData = data;
  }

  getUserData(){
    return this.userData
  }
}
```

Once you have setup like above you should be able to inject the `MyGlobalService` everywhere in your application and should get the data using the instance of the service like :

```
let userDataStored = this.myGlobalServcie.getUserData();
```

Hope it helps.