# Make Controller get information from a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, angular-controller

I have a directive, that in its scope has an object. This is static information right now and I want to make this visible for every controller in my app. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Create service to share the object, you can access it after inject with any controller or directive. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use global scope ($rootScope ) for example, if you want to use it everywhere

**UPDATE:**
some example and answer here:
[How do I use $rootScope in Angular to store variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880737/how-do-i-use-rootscope-in-angular-to-store-variables?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: how do I implement this? I'm fairly new to angularJS

Comment: That should have been a comment, not an answer

Comment: @Sh.Pavel this worked aswell and I will use this as a solution, since the information I want to store is call-specific so it makes no sense to store it in a directive or factory. Thanks!