# pass the value from one page to another using rootscope in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, rootscope

Login.js:

```
app.controller('LoginFormController', ['$scope','$http','$rootScope', '$state', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $state) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.authError = null;
    $scope.login = function() {
      $scope.authError = null;

      var emailId = $scope.user.email;
      var password = $scope.user.password;
      $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:8090/login/login',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

        },
        data: 'email='+emailId+'&password='+password
        //data: {'email': $scope.user.email, 'password': $scope.user.password}
      }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);


        if (response.data.status == 'SUCCESS') {

          $scope.user = response.data.user.firstName;
          $rootScope.test = response.data.user.firstName;
          console.log("check: ",$rootScope.test)
          $state.go('app.dashboard');
        } else {
          //alert('invalid login');
          $scope.authError = 'Email or Password not right';
        }
      }, function(x) {
        $scope.authError = 'Server Error';
      })
    };
}])
```

I saved the value under $rootScope.test

Here Is my App.main.js:

```
'use strict';
  angular.module('app').controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope',
   function($scope, $rootScope) {

    $scope.user5 = $rootScope.test;

  }
 ]);
```

trying to print the rootscope

> If I run this Code i am facing the error of $rootScope is undefined in the console. How to Resolve this

Comment: which controller you are getting error

Comment: Have you tried using `$scope.test` in main.js?

Comment: Instead of storing data on $rootScope, use a service. $rootScope is deprecated and using it will make migration to Angular 2+ more difficult. See also [AngularJS FAQ - $rootScope exists, but it can be used for evil](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#-rootscope-exists-but-it-can-be-used-for-evil)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$rootScope is the parent of all $scope, each $scope receives a copy of $rootScope data which you can access using $scope itself.

Here is a modified version
https://jsfiddle.net/sedhal/g08uecv5/17/

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.obj = {
      "name":"user1",
      "bdate":"18/11/1994",
      "city":"Ahmedabad"
    };
})
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
      $scope.data = $rootScope.obj;
})
.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, $rootScope) {
     $scope.data1 = $rootScope.obj;
});
```

Comment: This is useful for me @sedhal.

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18881189/9013688

Instead of passing directly your property on the $rootScope, you could emit an event which could be listened in an other part of your app like this:

```
if (response.data.status == 'SUCCESS') {
  $rootScope.$emit('user-logged', response.data.user.firstName)
}
```

And then:

`$rootScope.$on('user-logged', function(event, data){
  do something with your data
})`

Or you could use a service which is a good way to handle your data in all your app.

Comment: `$broadcast`, `$emit`, and `$on` are deprecated. Using them will make migration to Angular 2+ more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you take the advice of [`georgeawg`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5535245/georgeawg), his suggestion seems to be the best way to implement this functionality in my opinion.

I want to suggest what might be wrong with your example.

If you can see that in the main `App.main.js` you have given the declaration as

```
angular.module('app').controller(...
```

But you are using a variable `app` in `login.js` like so.

```
app.controller(...
```

Which I am assuming you are creating somewhere else. Thus the set `rootscope` value is lost because there are two instances of the same app.

---

The solution to your problem will be to declare one variable `app` which will store the instance of the app. So the fix for your solution will be to modify `App.main.js` to be like so.

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.controller(...
```

Also you need to remove any other arbitary `var app =` in your complete code, since these will create multiple instances of the same app.

I hope my explanation was understandable and the correct guess, please try out this solution!

Answer (score 0):

In your main js add this.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.test; 
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample implementation of george's suggestion which is the proper way to handle this.

```
app.controller('LoginFormController', ['$scope','$http','$rootScope', '$state', 'stateService', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $state, stateService) {
    var userFirstName = 'John';
    stateService.setFirstName('Bill');

    userFirstName = stateService.getFirstName(); 
    console.log(userFirstName); // result will be 'Bill'
}])
```

And the service which I usually call stateService

```
app.factory('stateService', [factory]);

function factory() {        
    var userFirstName = null;

    stateService.getFirstName = function() {
        return userFirstName;
    };

    stateService.setFirstName = function(firstName) {
        userFirstName = firstName;
    };

    return stateService;
}
```